# How to open the jQuery dialog from the Html.ActionLink of webgrid?RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

Here is the webgrid with `Html.ActionLink` in it:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
 displayHeader: false,
 htmlAttributes: new { id = "Grid2" },
  tableStyle: "webgrid-table-aigindex",
  selectedRowStyle: "selectRow", columns:
 grid.Columns(
 grid.Column(columnName: "Product_Name", header: "Product Name", format: @<text>@item.Prod_Name</text>), grid.Column(header: "Actions", format: (item) =>
                 new HtmlString(
                     Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                       Html.ActionLink("Invoice", "Invoice", new { id = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                        Html.ActionLink("Product", "Product", new { id = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                     Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-link" }).ToString()                      
                     ), style: "Action"

     ) ))
```

You can see the above code, I added class "delete-link" to the `ActionLink` of delete:

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-link" }).ToString()
```

and here is the jQuery code:

```
var deleteLinkObj;
// delete Link
$('#Grid2 .delete-link').click(function () {
    deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
    $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
    return false; // prevents the default behaviour

});
```

here is the HTML div for the jQuery dialogbox:

```
<div id="delete-dialog" style="display: none"  title="Delete Confirmation">
<p>
    Are you sure you want to delete this Product?
    @ViewBag.DeleteConfirmation
</p>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery dialogbox code:

```
$('#delete-dialog').dialog({  autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true,   buttons: {
 "Continue": function () {
      $.post(deleteLinkObj [0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action
         if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
            deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row
            //(optional) Display Confirmation
         }
         else {
            //(optional) Display Error
         }
        });
      $(this).dialog("close");
   },
  "Cancel": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      }
  } });
```

But the dialog doesn't popup, instead , the code went to the method of controller directly, the jQuery dialogbox is ignored,
here is the link of example I am trying to implement:
https://ricardocovo.com/2010/09/02/asp-mvc-delete-confirmation-with-ajax-jquery-ui-dialog/
Any idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: try passing `e` into your delete function. then in the first line do `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: is this what you mean? $('#Grid2 .delete-link').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();
    deleteLinkObj = $(this);     $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
    return false; 
});

Comment: Yes. this will stop any default behavior the link might have. Based on your description, it sounds like you're going to the server when you don't want to

Comment: yes, basically, I need the jQuery popup first before triggering the method of controller, and I also have buttons of "Continue" and "Cancel" on the popup window, only when user click "Continue" button, then the controller method will be executed, I may need to add the codes of jQuery dialogbox to help you understanding.